# A query on $\#P$ and $NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

We know that if a $\#P$-complete problem has a deterministic reduction to $FNP$ version of an $NP$-complete problem then polynomial hierarchy collapsed to first level.

Is there a consequence if we had a randomized reduction? By a randomized reduction here I mean a reduction that works for permanent of $\frac1{n^c}$ for some $c>0$ fraction of all matrices in $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$. Then by repeating the reduction polynomial number of times we can guarantee a reduction from any such matrix with probability $1-o(1)$.